# Whether the latest GDR from Microsoft includes all prior GDRs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, patching

I am looking at patching SQL server using the latest GDR (KB 5014356) from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/latest-updates-for-microsoft-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

I understand that GDR includes the security fixes. Where as CU includes security + functional fixes.

This question is to ask whether the GDR from the above link is a cumulative GDR (including all prior GDR's) or does this only install security fixes from this GDR (KB 5014356)? I'm not sure whether the GDR is cumulative because it just says GDR (there is also a CU16-GDR but I'm not sure what's that as I have always installed GDR), where as the other one CU is obviously cumulative based on its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GDRs are cumulative, including all the security updates in the previous GDRs.

[This article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/security-update-for-sql-server-2019-rtm-gdr/ba-p/3508228) confirms this for the GDR in question